# Find the antiderivatives if they exist

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

- $\int\overline{z}dz$
- $\int z\sin z^2 dz$
- $\int z\ln z dz$

If I consider a curve $C = \{z \in \mathbb{C} ~|~ |z|<1\}$ then $\oint_{C} \overline{z} \ dz = 2\pi i \neq 0  $,  therefore $\overline{z}$ has no antiderivative.

Now let's move on to the other two functions

$\oint_\gamma z\sin z^2 \ dz = \oint_\gamma z\ln z \ dz = 0$ for any piecewise smooth ,closed and simple curve $\gamma$ in $ \mathbb{C}$
because they're analytic ($\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$) so they both admit an antiderivative.

It might sound dumb but my question is now that I showed these two functions have an antiderivative, how do I compute them? Can I use the same methods (integration by parts and substitutions....etc) as in real analysis? Or should I proceed differently ? Thank you.

Comment: $\log(z)$ is not analytic for $|z|<1$.  There is a branch point at $z=0$.